# Parse OData QueryString filter to object, remove filter and create new path

Tags: c#, odata, httprequest

I am creating an OData service and added a 'dummy' column to my views that always returns an empty string. This way i can add some data to my requestheaders when i intercept my incoming request.

I have to do it this way since i have some consumers of my service who are unable to provide custom RequestHeaders but can apply this extra OData filtering.

To acomplish this right now i search on that part of the querystring and extract the part i want and replace it with an empty string. This solution works fine but it doesn't seem very elegant.

I started on writing my own lexer/parser for the filter part of my query string but it seems overly complex to implement, and very error phrone.

I have looked into the Microsoft Odata namespacing to see if i can find any uitable helpers/parsers to translate my filter into some sort of object graph but didn't identify any.

How can i convert this filter part on my server so i can safely remove 1 filter expression and recompile my filter to build the request path again.

my current code:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    string path = app.Context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

    var filter = "TokenValue%20eq%20%27";
    int pos = path.IndexOf(filter);
    if (pos > -1)
    {
        var query = path.Substring(0, pos + filter.Length);
        var filterpart = path.Substring(pos + filter.Length, path.Length - pos - filter.Length);
        var delimitedpart = "%27";
        var t = filterpart.IndexOf(delimitedpart);
        var tokenValue = filterpart.Substring(0, t);
        app.Context.Request.Headers["CustomToken"] = tokenValue;
        filterpart = filterpart.Substring(t, filterpart.Length - t);

        path = query + filterpart;
        app.Context.RewritePath(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/12/06/parsing-filter-and-orderby-using-the-odatauriparser.aspx